Create concrete of generic?
I have generated protobuf and want to make a concreate of message.
something like this:

type NatsSubscriber[T proto.Message] struct {
    NatsClient     *nats.Conn
    Log            logger.Log
    OnReceiveEvent func(event T) (response string)
}

func (n *NatsSubscriber[T]) RegisterHandlers() {
    for _, routeName := range n.Topics {
        _, err := n.NatsClient.Subscribe(routeName, func(req *nats.Msg) {
            uuids := req.Header[`UUID`]
            var uuid string
            if len(uuids) > 0 {
                uuid = uuids[0]
            }

            var event T // how to make this concrete?
            n.Log.Infof("natsClient[%T] %s receive %s", event, routeName, uuid)
            err := proto.Unmarshal(req.Data, event)
            if err != nil {
                n.Log.Errorf("natsClient[%T].Subscribe.Unmarshal: %s %s %v", event, uuid, routeName, err)
                err = req.Nak()
                if err != nil {
                    n.Log.Errorf("natsClient[%T].Subscribe.Nak: %s %s %v", event, uuid, routeName, err)
                }
                return
            }

            resp := n.OnReceiveEvent(event)
            if err := req.Respond([]byte(resp)); err != nil {
                n.Log.Errorf("natsClient[%T].Subscribe.Respond: %s %s %v", event, uuid, routeName, err)
            }
        })
        if err != nil {
            var event T
            n.Log.Errorf("natsClient[%T].Subscribe: %s %v", event, routeName, err)
        }
    }
}

and called by something like this:
blaSubscriber := NatsSubscriber[*apiProto.BlaReq]{
        NatsClient: natsClient,
        Topics:     topics1,
        Log:        log,
        OnReceiveEvent: func(event *apiProto.BlaReq) (resp string) {
           ...
        },
    }
fooSubscriber := NatsSubscriber[*apiProto.FooReq]{
        NatsClient: natsClient,
        Topics:     topics2,
        Log:        log,
        OnReceiveEvent: func(event *apiProto.FooReq) (resp string) {
           ...
        },
    }
...

If without protobuf, I can just use normal struct and it would deserialized normally.
fooSub := natsSubscriber[FooReq]{ ... }

// then on RegisterHandlers

var event T
msgpack.Unmarshal(req.Data, event) // no error because concreate

The problem is that apiProto.BlaReq have to be a pointer so it can satisfy the proto.Message interface on the generic, but that line will have error because I don't know how to make it a concrete from pointer
var event T // how to make this concrete?
err := proto.Unmarshal(req.Data, event) // pointer to nil

So how to make a concrete of pointer, or how to declare the generic as concrete but still satisfy the proto.Message interface?
already tried with this:
type protoAble[T proto.Message] interface {
    *FooReq | *BlaReq | ...
    //*T // not allowed
}

type NatsSubscriber[T any, PT protoAble[*T]] struct {
  ...
}

// and on RegisterHandlers

var event T
var pointer PT = &event // not allowed
err := proto.Unmarshal(req.Data, pointer)

or other attempt:
type protoAble[T any] interface {
    *FooReq | *BlaReq | ...
    proto.Message
    *T
}

also the same, cannot satisfy the proto.Message on calling
minimal code to reproduce: https://go.dev/play/p/4eLBwtyo5st

current solution: ptr, ok := any(event).(proto.Message)
